# $(*).click event click it and all of its parent.

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
<p>
    <div>
        <div><span>Hello</span></div>
        <span>Hello Again</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>And Hello Again</span>
    </div>
</p>
<b>Click Hellos to toggle their parents.</b>
<script>
    function showParents() {
        $("div").css("border-color", "white");
        var len = $("span.selected")
        .parents("div")
        .css("border", "2px red solid")
        .length;
        $("b").text("Unique div parents: " + len);
    }
    $("*").click(function () {
        $("b").text($(this).parents().length);
    });
</script>
```

The problem is when I click on a span, this shows 0 instead of 3!

I think the problem is `*`

Now the question is, how do I get the parent count when I don't know the type of the element?

Comment: Here is why: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: The way `.click()` on `*` works is by performing the action for each of the elements in the DOM starting at the one you clicked, and then "upwards" (or bubbling), because `<html>` is first in the tree, it has no parents.

Comment: tanx guys, i got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is event propagation(bubbling). The click event gets propagated to the root of the document from the clicked element triggering each of the click handler associated with those ancestor elements, so when the `html` element's click handler is triggered there is no more parents so you gets 0 as the result.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TK2TA/2/) - take a look at the console

Instead you can bind the click handler only to the document object then use the event's target property to find the element which triggered the click and find its parents

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    $("b").text($(e.target).parents().length);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TK2TA/)